# Why isn't my Python program printing anything to the console?

Tags: python-3.x, command-line

Here is my code...

```
from sys import argv

#python.exe app.py JSON
json = argv

print("Your JSON filepath is: " + json)
```

But when I run `>python app.py JSON` or `>python.exe app.py JSON` or even `python(.exe) app.py "JSON"` it doesn't print anything to the console. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you not even getting an error message saying it's impossible to concatenate a string and a list `argv`?

Comment: No. I also tried the `print("Done")`. That's not working either.

Comment: Are you sure you saved the file and that you're running the correct file? Try passing the full path to the file to the Python interpreter

Comment: still not working.